# Выбор специализации шаблонного класса с параметром по умолчанию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename = int>
struct A;

template<template<typename = double> class T>
void bar(T<int>) {
    T<>{}.foo();
}

template<>
struct A<int> {
    void foo() { std::cout << "int"; }
};

template<>
struct A<double> {
    void foo() { std::cout << "double"; }
};


int main() {
    bar<A>(A{});
}
```

Почему в данном случае выбирается специализация шаблонного класса для типа double, а не для типа int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что для параметров в шаблонном параметре шаблона можно задавать значения по-умолчанию и они будут использоваться в целевом шаблоне вместо тех, которые были у шаблона-параметра изначально:

> **17.1 Template parameters [temp.param]**
>
> 18 A template-parameter of a template template-parameter is permitted to have a default template-argument.
>   When such default arguments are specified, they apply to the template template-parameter in the scope of
>   the template template-parameter.

Соответственно `T<>{}.foo();` всегда инстанцируется как `T<double>{}.foo();`

Comment: Добавлю, что если в шаблонном параметре значения по умолчанию не указать вообще, то оригинальные значения по умолчанию работать все равно не будут.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Добавлю, что для того чтобы оригинальное значение по-умолчанию все-таки использовалось можно поменять параметр шаблонного параметра шаблона на пачку `template<template<typename...> class T>`